# Show available languages in content-view

Tags: views, 8, nodes, i18n-l10n

in older-drupal-versions when content was translated to different languages, it was possible to indicate in which other languages that content is available and in which not.

Let's say I have en, de and fr as languages. Foo is translated to en and de and bar is translated to fr only.

In my contents index (/admin/content) I want to display that linked info as:

<kbd>foo</kbd><kbd>en, de, <s>fr</s></kbd>
<kbd>bar</kbd><kbd><s>en</s>, <s>de</s>, fr</kbd>

Where clicking a non-striked text leads to the edit of the particular node and clicking the striked one will start a translation.

Is that, or something which gets close, possible in D8?

Answer (score 1):

@CG-monroe is correct that there isn't anything out of the box, but you can still list the language for each node, edit the content view (defaults to `/admin/structure/views/view/content`) and add `Translation language` to the fields, you can also add the `Original language` field if that is useful as well.

Comment: And a language filter option to the filters so you can see specific language. I forgot this wasn't standard since the mod was made on my ML sites so long ago...lol

Comment: Good point, I usually end up adding a few additional filters to the content now, depending on what the site requires.

Answer (score 0):

The content admin screen is now just a view.  AFAIK there is no view widget that will do that.

It probably would be possible to write a entity specific global widget for this.  Basically, you can get the list of installed languages from the language manager and then for each entity row use the getTranslations() method to find what has been translated.